How do I wait on an IBM PCjr?
I'm having trouble with a program I am trying to write for my PCjr, where I need to pause the program for an amount of time before running the next instruction. Here it is:
10 CLS
20 PRINT "|"
30 WAIT 1
40 CURSOR 1,1
50 PRINT "/"
60 WAIT 1
70 CURSOR 1,1
80 PRINT "-"
90 WAIT 1
100 CURSOR 1,1
110 PRINT "\"
120 WAIT 1
130 CURSOR 1,1
140 GOTO 20

When I ran this program I got:
|
Syntax error in 30
Ok
30 WAIT 1

Is there a command that waits some number of seconds defined by a number or variable that I can use in place of "WAIT n"?
I have tried replacing "WAIT n" with "SLEEP n", however that didn't help as it ultimately gave me:
|
Syntax error in 30
Ok
30 SLEEP 1

I ended up reverting the change after this.

Exactly which version of BASIC are you using? Have you considered a FOR...NEXT loop as a delay?

I'm using "The IBM Personal Computer Basic Version C1.20 Copyright IBM Corp 1981 62940 Bytes free Ok", or at least that's what it prints after booting up.

You're going to need to find the manual for that version of Basic. gist.github.com/jblang/e15753851e4bdffd00bd6307fbde5dad is somewhere to start looking.

You may be interested in https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com.

GW-BASIC and its derivatives (which include the BASIC you’re using) didn’t have a WAIT or SLEEP statement that would do what you are looking for. Generally, the desired effect was achieved by using a FOR...NEXT loop:
10 FOR I=1 TO 1000: NEXT I

where the delay desired was multiplied by a fixed amount (usually, the estimate was a count of 1000 was about one second) as the upper bound on the FOR.

Well, you fixed my problem, however now it's saying that the "CURSOR x,y" function is faulty. Does anyone know of a command that would work in place of "CURSOR x,y"?

@Mrredstone333 As mentioned above, you need to find a manual. It will answer questions like that. I wouldn't be surprised if you need to use POKE for things like that.

@Mrredstone333 - From the way you're using the CURSOR statement, it looks like you want LOCATE instead. Please find a manual for the version of BASIC you're using.

It worked! Thank you! :-D

The WAIT command is not directly related to timing! This statement waits for a byte at a specified port to exhibit a certain bitpattern:

WAIT p,a will cause your program to pause executing until (TheByteAtPortP AND a) is non-zero.
WAIT p,a,b will cause your program to pause executing until ((TheByteAtPortP XOR b) AND a) is non-zero.

For actual pausing a number of seconds (or fractions thereof) you can use the TIMER function. It returns the number of seconds (two decimal places) that have elapsed since midnight.
To position the cursor we use the LOCATE statement that can have up to 5 arguments. The first is the row and the second is the column. In your case you want both to be 1, that's easy enough:
10 CLS
20 PRINT "|"
30 GOSUB 200
40 LOCATE 1,1
50 PRINT "/"
60 GOSUB 200
70 LOCATE 1,1
80 PRINT "-"
90 GOSUB 200
100 LOCATE 1,1
110 PRINT "\"
120 GOSUB 200
130 LOCATE 1,1
140 GOTO 20

200 T = TIMER
210 WHILE TIMER < T + 1.5  ' Wait for 1.5 seconds
220 WEND
230 RETURN

Same program with a FOR-NEXT loop:
10 CLS
20 A$="|/-\"
30 FOR I = 1 TO LEN(A$)
40   LOCATE 1,1
50   PRINT MID$(A$,I,1);
60   T = TIMER
70   WHILE TIMER < T + 1  ' Wait for 1 second
80   WEND
90 NEXT I
100 GOTO 30

The TIMER gets reset at midnight
Under the exceptional circumstance that the above programs are executed very close to midnight, the condition TIMER < T + something could maybe stay true forever, which would then result in an infinite loop!
Recently, I wrote an answer for How to set 1 second time delay at assembly language 8086 and the solution that I have presented there does not have the problem I mentioned before. Below is an implementation in GW-BASIC:
10 CLS : A=0 : A$="|/-\"
20 FOR I=1 TO LEN(A$)
30   PRINT CHR$(8);MID$(A$,I,1);
40   FOR J=1 TO 3            ' 3 timer ticks is about 1/6 second
50     K=TIMER
60     WHILE TIMER=K : WEND  ' Wait for a changed timer value
70   NEXT J
80 NEXT I
90 A=A+1 : IF A<15 GOTO 20   ' Program runs for almost 10 seconds


Maybe PRINT CHR$(8); is step back instead of LOCATE 1,1.

@i486 I have used your idea to use the backspace instead of the LOCATE 1,1 statement. Because GW-BASIC uses a 'destructive' backspace (in contrast to BIOS that uses a 'non-destructive' backspace, I had to place the CHR$(8); before the MID$(A$,I,1);.
